# In Visual Studio (2010), how do I get the little method information help box to pop up again?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that `Ctr`+`Space` is to bring up intellisense for code completion, but how do I get this little box to pop up, which is the one that provides method and parameter info:

[image]

At the moment, if I lose it, I backspace the comma, then it pops up when I re-enter the comma. I'm sure there's a keyboard shortcut I'm missing though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bring it back up with

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: Related question: Does it have a name other than "little method information help box"?

Comment: @CamJackson, yes, [Parameter Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25cey46e.aspx)